# How to change the width of textarea when using TextArea tag

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

In `antd` library, inside a class named `ant-input`, a field called `350px !important` fixed the `width` of `textarea` to `350px`, and I can't overwrite this field.

I searched the document provided by `antd` https://ant.design/components/input-cn/, and they don't provide a api which allows me to change the width.

```css
.ant-input {
  color: var(--text-primary-color) !important;
  font-family: var(--text-primary-font-family);
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 350px !important;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--input-box-border-color) !important;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I expect to overwrite the `width` of the default value, but `!important` doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: You could get more specific, e.g. create a rule with the parent container `.container-class .ant-input { width: whatever !important; }`

Comment: Their [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nkl2z755wj) doesn't seem to have any hard width set on the `textarea`

Comment: It [seems to work for me](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMejzV). It might help to build a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to just pass the style argument like:

```
<Input.TextArea style={{ width: 500 }} />
```

See it here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/cocky-hugle-e9eu1

Answer (score 0):

For me, it did not work but this worked:

`<Input.TextArea style={{ width: 500, max-width: 500 }} />`

However, it proved not really reliable.